# Increase iOS App Security With Keychain

Tags: ios, security, ios5, ios6, keychain

I should develop iOS app that store very sensitive information and passwords. I find that iOS keychain is for this purpose, but there is something that bother me. If the phone is jailbroken how this affect to the keychain? Can someone access the information in it? How can I make the keychain more secure and protect the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keychain uses encryption - Apple assumes that an attacker has direct access to the filesystem of the device, and designed accordingly.

As long as you follow the best practices, you won't need to worry about jail breaking.